# Display AlertDialog from call screen in Android

Tags: android, screen, android-alertdialog

I want to display an alert in the call screen when the user initiates a call.

Currently I have:

- A class MyAlert extends Activity to view and process the alert
- A class CallReceiver extends BroadCastReceiver to process the call

From CallReceiver, I launch the alert with startActivity on MyAlert. The problem is that the alert appears in my main activity, so we don't see it at the right time, but only if we open the app, which is totally useless.

If anyone has any ideas, it would help me a lot; I lost hope!

Answer (score 0):

Call Screen is part of a separate application. Which means you would have to modify that source and install to get your functionality desired.  The WhitePAges app I believe in fact does this..

Comment: I saw some app doing this. For example, an app where if you click on the home button anywhere on the phone, home screen, call sreen etc, out of the app, you have a dialog whitout opening this app.  All i want is just have an AlertDialog above the call Screen and i don't know how. I mean how modify that source as you suggest?

Comment: You stated that dialog is only appearing when your application is open and running..if you run your application as boot service but generally that is somewhat discourage due to battery drain